# make a vertical multiheader in JTable with group option

Tags: jtable

I am using the existing code from [groupheader](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/GroupableGroupHeaderExample.htm) and [verticalHeader](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/vertical-table-header-cell-renderer/) to make a Jtable with grouping and vertical header. I am able to either make the headers look vertical or either group them, but cant achieve them together. All I get the following image. I want to make the "name" horizontal, but all the "To.." vertical text.

[image]

Following is my code.

```
    // Grouping of the columns
    ColumnGroup g_name = new ColumnGroup("name");
    g_name.add(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1));
    g_name.add(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2));
    g_name.add(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3));
    GroupableTableHeader header = (GroupableTableHeader) table.getTableHeader();
    header.addColumnGroup(g_name);


    // Vertical label for column header (but skip first cell header; it stays horizontal)
    Enumeration<TableColumn> columns = table.getColumnModel().getColumns();
    columns.nextElement();
    TableCellRenderer headerRenderer = new VerticalTableHeaderCellRenderer();
    while (columns.hasMoreElements())
        columns.nextElement().setHeaderRenderer(headerRenderer);
```

Answer (score 0):

For vertical aligment of text in header cells, you can use for example this
extension of BasicLabelUI:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.text.AttributedString;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI;

public class VerticalLabelUI extends BasicLabelUI {

    public VerticalLabelUI() {
    }

    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        return new VerticalLabelUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        // rotate 90 degrees
        g2.rotate(-Math.PI / 2, c.getSize().height / 2, c.getSize().height / 2);

        // apply word wrapping
        String text = ((JLabel) c).getText();
        if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setPaint(c.getForeground());
            Insets insets = c.getInsets();
            float x = insets.left;
            float y = insets.top;
            int w = c.getHeight() - insets.left - insets.right;
            AttributedString as = new AttributedString(text);
            AttributedCharacterIterator aci = as.getIterator();
            FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
            LineBreakMeasurer lbm = new LineBreakMeasurer(aci, frc);
            TextLayout tl;
            while (lbm.getPosition() < aci.getEndIndex()) {
                tl = lbm.nextLayout(w);
                tl.draw(g2, x, y + tl.getAscent());
                y += tl.getDescent() + tl.getLeading() + tl.getAscent();
            }
        }

        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
        return transposeDimension(super.getPreferredSize(c));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize(JComponent c) {
        return transposeDimension(super.getMaximumSize(c));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize(JComponent c) {
        return transposeDimension(super.getMinimumSize(c));
    }

    private Dimension transposeDimension(Dimension from) {
        return new Dimension(from.height, from.width + 2);
    }

}
```

To use it, locate your table and do something like:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer tableCellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
tableCellRenderer.setUI(new VerticalLabelUI());
myTable.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(tableCellRenderer);
```

*Note: It also does text wrapping, which is quite useful with vertical aligned text. In case you work with huge tables, make sure to properly implement `createUI` to no blow you memory.*